# Can we improve on the sample mean as an estimator of the true mean of a Pareto distribution, 1 < α < 2?

Tags: mean, estimators, pareto-distribution, fat-tails

Suppose I have a sample drawn from a population which is approximately distributed i.i.d. according to the Pareto distribution for values of x greater than X*. Suppose, moreover, that the tail index 1 < α  < 2, so the variance is infinite but the mean is finite.

I am interested in the value of the mean of the portion of this distribution which is greater than X*. (I am interested in the parameter α only as it bears on the mean.) Theory tells us that this number is equal to αX*/(α-1). However, numerical experiments (with R) tell me that, even for very large samples (in the millions) the variance of the sample mean is a large fraction of the true mean, and is highly influenced by the maximum observed sample value. For α  = 1.16, corresponding roughly to the "80:20 rule," the observed value is higher than the true value about a fifth of the time, but on those occasions it is generally a lot higher. Moreover, the observed variance of a million draws of a sample of a million is only slightly less than the observed variance of a million draws of a sample of a thousand from the same distribution.

Although we know from the law of large numbers that the mean converges to the true mean in the limit, it appears that it is not a particularly good estimate, in the sense of being reliably close to the true mean, for any sample it is feasible to collect. Moreover, given that the variance of x is infinite, the variance of the sample mean must also be infinite for finite n. So the observed sample variance is in some sense "infinitely bad" as en estimator of the true sample variance.

I am not certain that my question is well-defined; I have not been able to define it clearly in mathematical terms. But in essence, I would like to know if there is any estimate I  can construct from the sample that is reliably closer to the true mean than the sample mean, and if there is anything quantitative that can be said about how good that estimator is.

I can think of half a dozen plausible ways to estimate α -- an MLE from my sample, slope of the least squares line from a log-log transform, as ln(2)/(median(x)/X*) using the sample median, using the change of variable formula on log x (which I think is exponential), and so forth. And some of these estimators have good properties as estimators of α. But I am not looking for good properties of my estimator of α, but of my estimator of the mean, and I don't know how to select from among these estimates or what I can say about the quality of the resulting estimate.